# Claim: For all numbers x: if [x >= 6 and 2^(x) > 10x] then 2^(x+1) > 10(x+1). Please help me prove this!

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Im pretty sure the claim is true; Im just trying to prove this in a general case.

What I've got so far:

Let $x \in R$
Assume $x \geq 6$
Then $2 ^6 \geq 64$
Then $2 ^x > 10(x)$
Then $2^{x+1} \geq 128$
Then $2^{x+1} > 70$

I know it's missing a more general case. Can you please help? Thanks in advance.

EDIT (2nd attempt):

Let $x \in R$
Assume $x \geq 6$
Then $2^x > 10x$      # Since $x \geq 6$
Then $2^{x+1} = 2 \cdot 2^x = 2^x + 2^x$
Then $2^x + 2^x > 10(x+1) = 10x + 10$     # Since $ \forall a \in R: if a \geq 6$, then $2^a + 2^a > 10a + 10$

Comment: Hint: $2x \ge x+1$.

Answer (score 2):

$2^{x+1} = 2 * 2^x > 2 * 10x = 10x + 10x ≥ 10x + 60 ≥ 10x + 10 = 10 (x + 1)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $2^{x+1}=2\cdot 2^x=2^x+2^x$ and $10(x+1)=10x+10$.

Comment: Im not sure if you get notified when I edit it, but I tried to use your hint. Do you think it works>